# Fullcalendar : disableResizing is only working on month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, fullcalendar

I put three views in my fullcalendar : month, agendaWeek and agendaDay.
I need to activate drag & drop and forbidden events resizing.
I use this following solution to do that on each render event :

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar(
'renderEvent',
 {
    title: "event name",
    editable: true,
    disableResizing: true
 },
 true
);
```

It's only working in the month view, that is I can drag & drop and resize events in agendaWeek and agendaDay views.
How can I remove resizing in this views ?

Thanks.

Comment: In newer version you can set it by **eventDurationEditable: false**

Answer (score 4):

I try to use the calendar option `durationEditable:false` but it did not work. The workaround was to use CSS and hide the resize element:

```
.fc-resizer.fc-end-resizer {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

place `eventStartEditable: false` as shown here:

```
initialView: 'resourceTimeline',
slotMinWidth:1,
eventDurationEditable: false, // Disable Resize
eventStartEditable: false, // disable dreage drop
eventTimeFormat: {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  hour12: true
},
```

Its Working,
for More
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/disableResizing

Answer (score 0):

`disableResizing` is available only as a global setting in FullCalendar. So if you want to disable resizing of all events in the calendar, you simply set the setting when you initialize FullCalendar:

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    [...]
    disableResizing: true,
    [...]
});
```

If you want to disable resizing of specific events, you could take a look at [this pull request](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/pull/49/files).

Answer (score 0):

place `editable:false` as shown here:

```
  header:{
     left:'prev,next today',
     center:'title',
     right: 'agendaWeek, list, rrule'//'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable:false, // place it under header. it worked for me
```

Works for Version 3